# Relative path from colorPicker to menu button

Tags: dom, extjs

I have an extjs menu, in which, upon clicking a button, a colorPicker is opened.
When a color is selected, `onColorPickerSelect: function(colorpicker, color, eOpts)` springs into action. How do I select the button element in this function, taking the value of the `colorpicker` variable as my start point?

```
items: [
{
    xtype: 'button',
    itemId: 'color1',
    style: 'background-color:#fc0;',
    text: '1. Farbe',
    menu: {
        xtype: 'colormenu',
        listeners: {
            select: {
                fn: me.onColorPickerSelect,
                scope: me
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Does `up('menuitem')` work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I answer in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221245/sencha-onselect-in-colormenu-set-background-color-of-parent-button/20226428#20226428), use `var button = colorpicker.up('button');`

```
  onColorPickerSelect: function(colorpicker, color, e0pts) {
      var button = colorpicker.up('button');
      button.getEl().setStyle('background-color', '#' + color);
  }
```